# DIY chemistry - Calcium from bone

Tags: organic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry

I've gotten really into this subject lately from people who make their own cleaning agents and I was surprised how simplistic (although time consuming) everything was.

I am interested in making slaked lime. I've been putting wood ashes in my garden bed lately and it's been doing wonders but if I had a steady supply of home made lime that would do wonders.

I cook a lot on the weekends and I usually have a lot of bones left over. Some are cooked and some are uncooked. Could I use any to make quicklime with? I was trying to figure out a way to soften bones without leeching the calcium from them. I know I could use something more practical like egg shells but I have an abundance of bones lol

Thank you for any and all help.

Comment: Bones contains calcium hydroxyphosphate. When heated it will not produce any quicklime

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bone_ash - "Bone ash is a white material produced by the calcination of bones. Typical bone ash consists of about 55.82% calcium oxide, 42.39% phosphorus pentoxide, and 1.79% water."

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2214509520300036 - "The calcium oxide present in bone ash reacts with water to form calcium hydroxide: {CaO (s) + H2O (l) → Ca (OH)2 (s)}."  molecule of carbon dioxide (CO2), leaving quicklime."